# Calling Action of Area from main page in mvc4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, asp.net-mvc-areas

I have one project where I have Index page in my main site.

I want to call action of the controller which is in area "ABC"

I have controller "Account" in both i.e. in my main site as well as in my area ABC.

From main site page I want to call Action Index of Accountcontroller which is my area ABC.

What I tried is

```
@Html.ActionLink("User Profile","Index", new{Area="ABC"})
```

This points to

```
http://localhost:50010/ABC/Home
```

Which I don't want

I have also tried

```
@Html.ActionLink("User Profile","Index","Account", new{Area="ABC"})
```

This points to

```
http://localhost:50010?Length=7
```

I am not able to find the way to solve this.

Comment: What is the link that you want to get? Also, the second example is missing a comma after `"Account"`

Comment: I want link as http://localhost:50010/ABC/Account/ or http://localhost:50010/ABC/

Comment: comma was typing mistake here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Html.ActionLink("User Profile", "Index", "Account", new { Area = "ABC" }, new{})
```